# (co)homotopy groups of a differential graded algebra

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

There is a well-known homotopy theory of CDGAs (commutative differential graded $k$-algebras, where $k$ has characteristic zero, typically even $\mathbb{Q}$) in which the weak equivlences of interest are the quasi-isomorphisms, those $A \to B$ which induce isomorphisms in cohomology $H^*(A)\cong H^*(B)$.

Another invariant one can associate to a CDGA $A$ is its (co)homotopy $\pi^*(A):= H^*(Q(A))$ where $Q(A)=A \:/\: A^2$ is the complex of indecomposables.

My question is: does there exist a quasi-isomorphism $A\to B$ that does *not* induce isomorphisms in cohomotopy?

It appears that when $A$ and $B$ are cofibrant (ie. Sullivan algebras), then a quasi-isomorphism $A\to B$ *does* induce isomorphisms $\pi^*(A)\cong \pi^*(B)$. Yet I cannot think of an example of a quasi-isomorphism that wouldn't have this property.

Any suggestion would be of great help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be $\mathbb{Q}$ concentrated in degree $2i$ and $W \xrightarrow{\simeq} X$ be a Sullivan model. I claim $Q(W) \rightarrow Q(X)$ is not a quasi-isomorphism. Note that $W$ is a Sullivan model of the sphere $S^{2i}$ and so $H_k(Q(W))$ is naturally isomorphic to $\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_k(S^{2i}),\mathbb{Q})$. $Q(W)$ has nontrivial homology in degree $4i-1$ since $S^{2i}$ has a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ in this homotopy group. Since $X$ is concentrated in degree $2i$, $Q(X)$ obviously is trivial in degree $4i-1$.